# How to render data with useEffect once, when the data is not in the main component? React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I imported data with Axios, and now I want to see them in the console only once, only with the first render, the problem is when I use useEffect in the component when it is not the main component, I get

This error:
[image: this error:]

This is the secondary component:
[image: This is the secondary component]

The main component:
[image: The main component]

Comment: Your problem doesn't see to be related to logging the data. Please check if `setCities` is being called again someplace else

Comment: The data is displayed on the console but also I get that error

Comment: Hi @TamarLaufer, welcome to SO, to help you much better with your problem instead of sharing your code into images, use code snippets, please check here [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9676887)

Answer (score 1):

the `cities.map` is executed each time the componentes is rendered, but you are changing the state of the component with the `setCityId` function and due this the components is rendered again, and then executes the `cities.map` again, and then the state changes again...
This causes the infinite loop.